# How I can get the list of application consuming battery power in android?

Tags: java, android, performance, battery

I am building an android application which gives battery information to user. I am able to get the current percentage of battery and standalone time.

I am facing an issue to get the list of android applications of that particular device which are consuming battery as per acceding order.

Some of the applications which are doing that are like DU Battery Saver. I am new in android please suggest some idea how to deal with this issue.

Comment: There is no way to get this information not having root access

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Battery usage of each application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149121/android-battery-usage-of-each-application)

Comment: @VladMatvienko How can we have root access of android application.

Comment: @VladMatvienko how other application are showing the list then ?

Comment: user's device have to be rooted, and user has to grant you a root access firstly. Then you can run the linux root commands to get yourth required info.

Comment: Which applications are? give an example

Comment: ok, looks like it is possible, but you'll have to do a lot of work to achieve final result. Here is an answer, which can make a start for you http://stackoverflow.com/a/30164919/1568530

Comment: @VladMatvienko Could you please give me a example or tutorial

Comment: "user's device have to be rooted..." not correct, at least not currently and not for some apps, like GSAM labs battery monitor