# Is there a way to measure and compare battery consumption of deep learning models when deployed in a mobile phone?

Tags: android-studio, deep-learning, tensorflow-lite

I have tried developing my own classifier application using **tensorflow-lite** and **android studio**. I want to be able to measure and compare their battery consumption during inference. I've tried looking at the energy profiler, but unfortunately, there are no absolute numbers - only estimations (light, medium, and heavy). Is there a tool where I can accurately measure the battery/energy consumption parameter?

[image]

Comment: You might need some special device to measure power consumption accurately. For example devices sold by monsoon https://www.msoon.com/

Comment: Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23311058/android-programmatically-get-battery-usage-per-application) question. Currently, it seems impossible to access battery usage data from the OS.